# duino bleep code not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to run the following nodejs code, based on the duino module found here: https://github.com/ecto/duino

bleep.js:

```
var arduino = require("duino");
var board = new arduino.Board();

var led = new arduino.Led({
  board: board,
  pin: 13
});

var bleep = function() {
  led.on();
  setTimeout(function() {
    led.off();
  }, 100);
}
setInterval( bleep, 1000 );
```

**EDIT**
Based on zmo's suggestion, I am now running du.ino (found under duino/src/) on my arduino board and bleep.js on my laptop.

Whilst compiling bleep.js, I get the following error:
Error: Cannot open /dev/

I was trying to trace back to where the path is being set.
I have traced this error to duino/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js

May I know how the following line (found in serialport.js) works?

```
function SerialPort(path, options, openImmediately, callback) {
```

Before this function is called on line 49, the 'path' variable is [object Object].
But after, it becomes /dev/

where does the change take place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhuh... where to start.

It looks like you're trying to compile your js code as an arduino sketch `.ino` files using the arduino ide. That can't work, it should be C++ code.